# Data Formatting after fetching from mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, struts2

I am sending data in database 
Like

```
Hello fnds,
            How are you.
```

I am fetching data from my sql and displaying in jsp page.

its showing

> Hello fnds, How are you.

in same line.
i want to display as i entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the text with `<PRE>` and `</PRE>` tags to preserve formatting in the browser